# Post Data Form login values through Url for generation of Token

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I have a question on the post the login values through service URL(http://test.azurewebsites.net/token) in this format.
Username=username.com&password=password&grant_type=password for generation of token .How can i do this one,if you have any idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit username and password to another url you can just add it to the url when calling it.

```
www.google.at => www.google.at?Username=username.com&password=password&grant_type=password
```

Anyway, I would recommend to sent it via a POST call. A java example:

```
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
```

Comment: Not to another url